# How to return array of object use json file in angularjs factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I created sample for services call which is Working fine Call one by one [Link for sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/dyWJ52njUt4uL46QOYBg?p=preview).

like this:-

```
     JSONService.getJSON('file.json').then(function(data){
       $scope.languages = data;
  });

 JSONService.getJSON('file1.json').then(function(data){
       $scope.languages1 = data;
  });
```

I don't want to send separately. why because if its only two three call means fine.but 
I need to do more than 100 calls. that time I can't do one by one.
so tried like this

```
      JSONService.getJSON('file.json,file1.json').then(function(data){
       $scope.languages = data[0];
       $scope.languages1 = data[1];
  });
```

In services use split the values and try to push the promise one by one and return as array its not working I don't know where i did mistake can any one help me on this..

```
app.service('JSONService', function($http){  
   var data = [];
    return{
        getJSON: function(url){
          var parameter=url.split(',');
          for(var i=0; i< parameter.length; i++){
             $http.get(parameter[i])
                .then(function(response){
                    data.push(response);
                });
          }
          return data;
        }
    };
 });
```

[Link for Sample 2 not working](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjGzYuslOl1auwXi8LCO?p=preview)

Comment: Standard failure to get async result..? At the time the array is returned it will still be empty (and if/how this interacts with the remainder of the code depends on usage). It would be much better to compose the Promises (and hopefully limit the number of in-flight requests to something 'reasonable'), returning a single Promise that represents completion of the entire task - then it could be used 'as if' it was a normal service call, independently of how it aggregated/managed the request(s).

Comment: Also, what is up with the use of `$scope` here? :{ I would probably also accept an Array from the get-go, `getAwesomeFiles(['json1', 'json2', ..])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use promises for that. here is the service you need to use

```
app.service('JSONService', function($http, $q){  
   var data = [];
    return{
        getJSON: function(url){
          var urls = url.split(','),
              promises = [];
          for(var i=0; i< urls.length; i++){
             var inPromise  = $http.get(urls[i])
                .then(function(response){
                    data.push(response.data);
                });
              promises.push(inPromise);
          }
        //return the promise from the $q.all, that makes sure, that all pushed promises are ready and return the chapters.
        return $q.all(promises).then(function () {
            return data;
        });

        }
    };
 });
```

Also updated your plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/smMv9jPyMRNYX2AzAuRC?p=preview. This concatenates all the result to one array object `languages`

Comment: Hi, Narendra CM. Even in this also contain some problem http://plnkr.co/edit/Q9QJKVU59iPduoNjb2mf?p=preview data[0] need to return three value and data[1] should rerun 2 values right but some binding problem is there can check and let me know what was the problem

Comment: Logic working fine. but if i call languages1 in ng repeat some binding problem is there...

Comment: I think its not return array of array. within single array it include all object..

Comment: what I exactly need [array[0], array[1]] array[0] contain three data and array[0] contain two data. @Narendra CM

Comment: How can I know what was the data of 1st promise and  what was the data of another?

Comment: The above code works exactly the way you want. data[0] will have the response from first request and data[1] from second request. plunker just shows how to concatenate all the requests into one response.

Comment: JSONService.getJSON('file.json,file1.json').then(function(data){
       $scope.languages = data;
       $scope.languages1 = data[1];
  }); your mention like this in controller right. can u bind language1 then you will come to now @ Narendra CM

Comment: language1 return {"name":"Russian","value":false} this not [ {"name":"German", "value":false},
    {"name":"Russian","value":false},
    {"name":"Korean", "value":false}]

Comment: In your code simply bind <p>{{languages1}}</p> then you will come know what was the problem? @ Narendra CM

Comment: check this updated plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/smMv9jPyMRNYX2AzAuRC?p=preview. To access contents of json files, you need to use `data["file.json"]` and `data["file1.json"]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103194/discussion-between-narendra-cm-and-suresh-b).

Answer (score 0):

**$q**

This is what $q is for.

```
app.service("JSONService", ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q){
    return {
        getJson: function(callback){
            _urls = ["data1.json", "data2.json", "data3.json"],
            _urlCalls = [],
            _data = [];

            angular.forEach(_urls, function(url) {
                _urlCalls.push($http.get(url));
            });

            $q.all(_urlCalls).then(
                function(results) {
                    results.forEach(function(e,i){
                        _data.push(e.data);
                    });
                    callback(_data);
                 },
                 function(errors) {},
                 function(updates) {}
            );
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Usage**

From the controller.

```
JSONService.getJson(function(response){
    console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: can give me runable sample? @pedro